# Jekyll not working on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ruby, jekyll

My Google search showed that this question was asked here and then deleted by the asker, so I'm not sure if I'm asking something stupidly obvious.

I'm trying to start a jekyll project after upgrading to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. When I put in `jekyll`, I get the error: `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby2.1’: No such file or directory`.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I was running in the same problem as you, what I did so far is:

`sudo apt-get purge jekyll*`

To remove erverything related to jekyll, then I:

`sudo gem install jekyll`

To install as a gem of my `ruby2.3`, after that I tried to run my local website with:

`jekyll serve`

And it ran flawlessly. :-)